# Restore commit for moving file

Tags: git

I created file A  and commit this file. Then i rename that file to file B using just `mv` command and commit again. If I need to restore file A, how can I do this with git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git checkout <commit_id> <old_file_name>`. Here the `<commit_id>` would be the commit_id before the rename commit was done.

For example. Lets say commit_id2 was where you renamed and committed the file B and commit_id1 was the commit before commit_id2. Then in your case you need to do `git checkout commit_id1 A`

Comment: What if I forgot the name of that file..??

Comment: I just remember some content of that file, but I dont know what exactly the name of that file, for example if the name of that file too long...

Comment: You can do a do a `git checkout commit_id1`. But keep in mind, this will set all your changes back to what you would have at point of commit_id1. Another simple way to do this would be create a new branch based off the older commit. The way to do this would be `git checkout -b <new_branch_name> commit_id1`. Now you get the file back and you know the file name. You can switch back to your branch of interest by doing `git checkout <branch_of_interest>`. Kindly accept the solution if it helps you.